# Nativescript-Vue close modal after timeout

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am opening a modal component from a Nativescript-Vue function which opens fine

`this.$showModal(SuccessModal).then(() => { console.log('Modal Closed') });`

I can call `$modal.close` from a button within the modal but getting `$modal is undefined` if I try to call this from, say, the `mounted()` hook.

I want the modal to close on its own after a three second timeout rather than the user having to click outside of the modal.

How would I go about this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my end, can you setup a minimal Playground sample?

Comment: @Manoj https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=cipUop&v=3 That shows a basic modal so where/how would I automatically close the modal after a set time rather than having to touch the screen?

Comment: I don't see any code related to `$modal.close` in your sample, please share the complete sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I have updated the Playground to show that `$modal.close` returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the traditional syntax for function you loose the current context (this), use arrow functions to avoid that.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.$modal.close();
}, 3000);
```

Or you will have to keep reference to context in a variable

```
var me = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    me.$modal.close();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a twist on @Manoj's response.
Instead of using an external variable to bind the global `this`, you could use a `.bind()` in your native (non-arrow) function if you're inclined to do so, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.$modal.close();
}.bind($this), 3000);
```